# how I delete combination rows that have the same numbers from matrix and only keeping one of the combinations?

Tags: matlab, duplicates, pythagorean

```
 for a=1:50; %numbers 1 through 50
    for b=1:50;
        c=sqrt(a^2+b^2);

        if c<=50&c(rem(c,1)==0);%if display only if c<=50 and c=c/1 has remainder of 0

           pyth=[a,b,c];%pythagorean matrix

           disp(pyth)
        else c(rem(c,1)~=0);%if remainder doesn't equal to 0, omit output

        end      
    end   
end

answer=
        3     4     5
        4     3     5
        5    12    13
        6     8    10
        7    24    25
        8     6    10
        8    15    17
        9    12    15
        9    40    41
       10    24    26
       12     5    13
       12     9    15
       12    16    20
       12    35    37
       14    48    50
       15     8    17
       15    20    25
       15    36    39
       16    12    20
       16    30    34
       18    24    30
       20    15    25
       20    21    29
       21    20    29
       21    28    35
       24     7    25
       24    10    26
       24    18    30
       24    32    40
       27    36    45
       28    21    35
       30    16    34
       30    40    50
       32    24    40
       35    12    37
       36    15    39
       36    27    45
       40     9    41
       40    30    50
       48    14    50
```

This problem involves the Pythagorean theorem but we cannot use the built in function so I had to write one myself. The problem is for example columns 1 & 2 from the first two rows have the same numbers. How do I code it so it only deletes one of the rows if the columns 1 and 2 have the same number combination? I've tried unique function but it doesn't really delete the combinations. I have read about deleting duplicates from previous posts but those have confused me even more. Any help on how to go about this problem will help me immensely!

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post your code and data as images. In order for us to reproduce the issue and correct your code, we have to now type it in manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

The problem in your code seems to be, that `pyth` only contains 3 values, `[a, b, c]`. The `unique()` funcion used in the next line has no effect in that case, because only one row is contained in `pyth`. another issue is, that the values `idx` and `out` are calculated in each loop cycle. This should be placed after the loops. An example code could look like this:

```
pyth = zeros(0,3);

for a=1:50
    for b=1:50
        c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2);  
        if c<=50 && rem(c,1)==0
            abc_sorted = sort([a,b,c]);
            pyth = [pyth; abc_sorted];

        end
    end
end

% do final sorting outside of the loop
[~,idx]  = unique(pyth, 'rows', 'stable');
out = pyth(idx,:);
disp(out)
```

a few other tips for writing MATLAB code:

- You do not need to end `for` or `if`/`else` stements with a semicolon
- [`else` statements](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) cover any other case not included before, so they do not need a condition.

Some performance reommendations:

- Due to the symmetry of `a` and `b` (a^2 + b^2 = b^2 + a^2) the b loop could be constrained to `for b=1:a`, which would roughly save you half of the loop cycles.
- if you use `&&` for contencation of scalar values, the second part is not evaluated, if the first part already fails ([source](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html)).

Regards,

Chris

Comment: Thank you, I was using the sort function incorrectly earlier and I was missing the zeros(0,3) as you can see from my older code
            if c<=50&c(rem(c,1)==0)
               pyth=[a,b,c];%pythagorean matrix
              pyth = unique(sort(pyth,1), 'rows');
           [~,idx] = unique(sort(pyth,2),'rows','stable')
             out = pyth(idx,:);
             disp(out)
        else c(rem(c,1)~=0);
             
        end 
    Can you explain why did you used zeros(0,3)?

Comment: `pyth = [pyth; abc_sorted];` appends the new `a`/`b`/`c` valuse to the `pyth` matrix row-wise, so in iteration 1 the array has to be initialized with width 3 (and 0 rows), such that something can be appended.

Answer (score 0):

You can also linearize your algorithm (but we're still using bruteforce):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:50,1:50);                             %generate all the combination
C     = (X(:).^2+Y(:).^2).^0.5;                          %sums of two square for every combination
ind   = find(rem(C,1)==0 & C<=50);                       %get the index
res   = unique([sort([X(ind),Y(ind)],2),C(ind)],'rows'); %check for uniqueness
```

Now you could really optimized your algorithm using math, you should read this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/number-of-integer-solutions-of-x2-y2-k). It will be useful if n>>50.